# How to sign a txt file with a PGP key in C# using Bouncy Castle library

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp, sign

Does anyone have an example of how I can sign a txt file, using a PGP key in C# and Bouncy Castle library. Not to encrypt the file, only to add a signature.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void SignFile(String fileName, 
                     Stream privateKeyStream,
                     String privateKeyPassword,                      
                     Stream outStream)
{

    PgpSecretKey pgpSec = ReadSigningSecretKey(privateKeyStream);
    PgpPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = null;

    pgpPrivKey = pgpSec.ExtractPrivateKey(privateKeyPassword.ToCharArray());
    PgpSignatureGenerator sGen = new PgpSignatureGenerator(pgpSec.PublicKey.Algorithm, KeyStore.ParseHashAlgorithm(this.hash.ToString()));

    sGen.InitSign(PgpSignature.BinaryDocument, pgpPrivKey);

    foreach (string userId in pgpSec.PublicKey.GetUserIds()) {
        PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();

        spGen.SetSignerUserId(false, userId);
        sGen.SetHashedSubpackets(spGen.Generate());
    }

    CompressionAlgorithmTag compression = PreferredCompression(pgpSec.PublicKey);
    PgpCompressedDataGenerator cGen = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(compression);

    BcpgOutputStream bOut = new BcpgOutputStream(cGen.Open(outStream));
    sGen.GenerateOnePassVersion(false).Encode(bOut);

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
    FileStream fIn = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    PgpLiteralDataGenerator lGen = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
    Stream lOut = lGen.Open(bOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, file);

    int ch = 0;
    while ((ch = fIn.ReadByte()) >= 0) {
        lOut.WriteByte((byte)ch);
        sGen.Update((byte) ch);
    }

    fIn.Close();
    sGen.Generate().Encode(bOut);
    lGen.Close();
    cGen.Close();
    outStream.Close();
}

public PgpSecretKey ReadSigningSecretKey(Stream inStream)
// throws IOException, PGPException, WrongPrivateKeyException
{        
    PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = CreatePgpSecretKeyRingBundle(inStream);
    PgpSecretKey key = null;
    IEnumerator rIt = pgpSec.GetKeyRings().GetEnumerator();
    while (key == null && rIt.MoveNext())
    {
        PgpSecretKeyRing kRing = (PgpSecretKeyRing)rIt.Current;
        IEnumerator kIt = kRing.GetSecretKeys().GetEnumerator();
        while (key == null && kIt.MoveNext()) 
        {
            PgpSecretKey k = (PgpSecretKey)kIt.Current;
            if(k.IsSigningKey)
                key = k;
        }
    }

    if(key == null)
      throw new WrongPrivateKeyException("Can't find signing key in key ring.");
    else
        return key;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am very new to PGP have have to encrypt my csv in pgp format for some requirment, I have found code to implement that but still struggling to undersatand keystore and Keys. Could you suggest from where i can get keys? Public and private.

Comment: what all reference should be added for the above code..? i'm getting error in "PreferredCompression" and CreatePgpSecretKeyRingBundle(inStream) these are not identified as method.

Comment: @deepu: PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inStream));

Comment: what is outstream for?

Comment: This code does not compile.  Line: PgpSignatureGenerator sGen = new PgpSignatureGenerator(pgpSec.PublicKey.Algorithm, KeyStore.ParseHashAlgorithm(this.hash.ToString())); includes "KeyStore" and this.hash which are invalid.

Answer (score 3):

DidiSoft's code in a working fashion:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;


namespace BouncyCastleTest.PGP
{

    // http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.bcpg.HashAlgorithmTags
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337985/how-to-sign-a-txt-file-with-a-pgp-key-in-c-sharp-using-bouncy-castle-library
    class SignOnly
    {


        public void SignFile(string hashAlgorithm, string fileName, System.IO.Stream privateKeyStream
            , string privateKeyPassword, System.IO.Stream outStream)
        {

            PgpSecretKey pgpSec = ReadSigningSecretKey(privateKeyStream);
            PgpPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = null;

            pgpPrivKey = pgpSec.ExtractPrivateKey(privateKeyPassword.ToCharArray());




            PgpSignatureGenerator sGen = new PgpSignatureGenerator(pgpSec.PublicKey.Algorithm, ParseHashAlgorithm(hashAlgorithm));

            sGen.InitSign(PgpSignature.BinaryDocument, pgpPrivKey);

            foreach (string userId in pgpSec.PublicKey.GetUserIds())
            {
                PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();

                spGen.SetSignerUserId(false, userId);
                sGen.SetHashedSubpackets(spGen.Generate());
            }

            CompressionAlgorithmTag compression = PreferredCompression(pgpSec.PublicKey);
            PgpCompressedDataGenerator cGen = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(compression);

            BcpgOutputStream bOut = new BcpgOutputStream(cGen.Open(outStream));
            sGen.GenerateOnePassVersion(false).Encode(bOut);

            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
            System.IO.FileStream fIn = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
            PgpLiteralDataGenerator lGen = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
            System.IO.Stream lOut = lGen.Open(bOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, file);

            int ch = 0;
            while ((ch = fIn.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            {
                lOut.WriteByte((byte)ch);
                sGen.Update((byte)ch);
            }

            fIn.Close();
            sGen.Generate().Encode(bOut);
            lGen.Close();
            cGen.Close();
            outStream.Close();
        }


        public static PgpSecretKeyRingBundle CreatePgpSecretKeyRingBundle(System.IO.Stream keyInStream)
        {
            return new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyInStream));
        }


        public PgpSecretKey ReadSigningSecretKey(System.IO.Stream keyInStream) 
        {
            PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = CreatePgpSecretKeyRingBundle(keyInStream);
            PgpSecretKey key = null;
            System.Collections.IEnumerator rIt = pgpSec.GetKeyRings().GetEnumerator();
            while (key == null && rIt.MoveNext())
            {
                PgpSecretKeyRing kRing = (PgpSecretKeyRing)rIt.Current;
                System.Collections.IEnumerator kIt = kRing.GetSecretKeys().GetEnumerator();
                while (key == null && kIt.MoveNext())
                {
                    PgpSecretKey k = (PgpSecretKey)kIt.Current;
                    if (k.IsSigningKey)
                        key = k;
                }
            }

            if (key == null)
                throw new System.Exception("Wrong private key - Can't find signing key in key ring.");
            else
                return key;
        }



        public static string GetDigestName(int hashAlgorithm)
        {
            switch ((Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag)hashAlgorithm)
            {
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1:
                    return "SHA1";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.MD2:
                    return "MD2";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.MD5:
                    return "MD5";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.RipeMD160:
                    return "RIPEMD160";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha256:
                    return "SHA256";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha384:
                    return "SHA384";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha512:
                    return "SHA512";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha224:
                    return "SHA224";
                case Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Tiger192:
                    return "TIGER";
                default:
                    throw new Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpException("unknown hash algorithm tag in GetDigestName: " + hashAlgorithm);
            }
        }


        public static Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag ParseHashAlgorithm(string hashAlgorithm)
        {
            switch (hashAlgorithm.ToUpper())
            {
                case "SHA1":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1;
                case "MD2":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.MD2;
                case "MD5":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.MD5;
                case "RIPEMD160":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.RipeMD160;
                case "SHA256":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha256;
                case "SHA384":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha384;
                case "SHA512":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha512;
                case "SHA224":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Sha224;
                case "TIGER":
                    return Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.HashAlgorithmTag.Tiger192;
                default:
                    throw new Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpException("unknown hash algorithm name in ParseHashAlgorithm: " + hashAlgorithm);
            }
        }


        public static CompressionAlgorithmTag PreferredCompression(PgpPublicKey publicKey)
        {
            return CompressionAlgorithmTag.BZip2;
        }

    }


}
```

There is also an example in the BouncyCastle source-code (including how to verify):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;


using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp;

namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.Examples
{
    /**
    * A simple utility class that signs and verifies files.
    * <p>
    * To sign a file: SignedFileProcessor -s [-a] fileName secretKey passPhrase.<br/>
    * If -a is specified the output file will be "ascii-armored".</p>
    * <p>
    * To decrypt: SignedFileProcessor -v fileName publicKeyFile.</p>
    * <p>
    * <b>Note</b>: this example will silently overwrite files, nor does it pay any attention to
    * the specification of "_CONSOLE" in the filename. It also expects that a single pass phrase
    * will have been used.</p>
    * <p>
    * <b>Note</b>: the example also makes use of PGP compression. If you are having difficulty Getting it
    * to interoperate with other PGP programs try removing the use of compression first.</p>
    */
    public sealed class SignedFileProcessor
    {
        private SignedFileProcessor() {}

        /**
        * verify the passed in file as being correctly signed.
        */
        private static void VerifyFile(
            Stream  inputStream,
            Stream  keyIn)
        {
            inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);

            PgpObjectFactory            pgpFact = new PgpObjectFactory(inputStream);
            PgpCompressedData           c1 = (PgpCompressedData) pgpFact.NextPgpObject();
            pgpFact = new PgpObjectFactory(c1.GetDataStream());

            PgpOnePassSignatureList     p1 = (PgpOnePassSignatureList) pgpFact.NextPgpObject();
            PgpOnePassSignature         ops = p1[0];

            PgpLiteralData              p2 = (PgpLiteralData) pgpFact.NextPgpObject();
            Stream                      dIn = p2.GetInputStream();
            PgpPublicKeyRingBundle      pgpRing = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn));
            PgpPublicKey                key = pgpRing.GetPublicKey(ops.KeyId);
            Stream                      fos = File.Create(p2.FileName);

            ops.InitVerify(key);

            int ch;
            while ((ch = dIn.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            {
                ops.Update((byte)ch);
                fos.WriteByte((byte) ch);
            }
            fos.Close();

            PgpSignatureList    p3 = (PgpSignatureList)pgpFact.NextPgpObject();
            PgpSignature        firstSig = p3[0];
            if (ops.Verify(firstSig))
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("signature verified.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("signature verification failed.");
            }
        }

        /**
        * Generate an encapsulated signed file.
        *
        * @param fileName
        * @param keyIn
        * @param outputStream
        * @param pass
        * @param armor
        */
        private static void SignFile(
            string  fileName,
            Stream  keyIn,
            Stream  outputStream,
            char[]  pass,
            bool    armor,
            bool    compress)
        {
            if (armor)
            {
                outputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(outputStream);
            }

            PgpSecretKey pgpSec = PgpExampleUtilities.ReadSecretKey(keyIn);
            PgpPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = pgpSec.ExtractPrivateKey(pass);
            PgpSignatureGenerator sGen = new PgpSignatureGenerator(pgpSec.PublicKey.Algorithm, HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1);

            sGen.InitSign(PgpSignature.BinaryDocument, pgpPrivKey);
            foreach (string userId in pgpSec.PublicKey.GetUserIds())
            {
                PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
                spGen.SetSignerUserId(false, userId);
                sGen.SetHashedSubpackets(spGen.Generate());
                // Just the first one!
                break;
            }

            Stream cOut = outputStream;
            PgpCompressedDataGenerator cGen = null;
            if (compress)
            {
                cGen = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTag.ZLib);

                cOut = cGen.Open(cOut);
            }

            BcpgOutputStream bOut = new BcpgOutputStream(cOut);

            sGen.GenerateOnePassVersion(false).Encode(bOut);

            FileInfo                    file = new FileInfo(fileName);
            PgpLiteralDataGenerator     lGen = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
            Stream                      lOut = lGen.Open(bOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, file);
            FileStream                  fIn = file.OpenRead();
            int                         ch = 0;

            while ((ch = fIn.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            {
                lOut.WriteByte((byte) ch);
                sGen.Update((byte)ch);
            }

            fIn.Close();
            lGen.Close();

            sGen.Generate().Encode(bOut);

            if (cGen != null)
            {
                cGen.Close();
            }

            if (armor)
            {
                outputStream.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void Main(
            string[] args)
        {
            // TODO provide command-line option to determine whether to use compression in SignFile
            if (args[0].Equals("-s"))
            {
                Stream keyIn, fos;
                if (args[1].Equals("-a"))
                {
                    keyIn = File.OpenRead(args[3]);
                    fos = File.Create(args[2] + ".asc");

                    SignFile(args[2], keyIn, fos, args[4].ToCharArray(), true, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    keyIn = File.OpenRead(args[2]);
                    fos = File.Create(args[1] + ".bpg");

                    SignFile(args[1], keyIn, fos, args[3].ToCharArray(), false, true);
                }
                keyIn.Close();
                fos.Close();
            }
            else if (args[0].Equals("-v"))
            {
                using (Stream fis = File.OpenRead(args[1]),
                    keyIn = File.OpenRead(args[2]))
                {
                    VerifyFile(fis, keyIn);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("usage: SignedFileProcessor -v|-s [-a] file keyfile [passPhrase]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```