# Verify a PgP Encrypted and Signed file with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, sign, verify

I'm signing a document using PgP with the help of the bouncycastle library in c#. How do I verify a signed document to ensure that it is signed by the correct person or to even identify who signed it.

I'm using the code from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337985/how-to-sign-a-txt-file-with-a-pgp-key-in-c-using-bouncy-castle-library) with some little modifications to sign the file. The keys are self generated.

Edit:
I'm able to verify a signed file using information from this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/SignedFileProcessor.java.htm). In an encrypted and signed file, I'm however unable to get the `PgpSignatureList` to use for verification. I'm however able to get the LiteralData and decryption works.

regards

Comment: Found an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/SignedFileProcessor.java.htm). It is in java but I dont think it will be so different. I'm checking it out. If there are any other examples, I'll be happy to look at them.

Answer (score 1):

The Bouncy Castle C# project contains [an equivalent example](http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/csharp/crypto/test/src/openpgp/examples/SignedFileProcessor.cs?view=markup).